# Insert data in MySQL through java function

Tags: java, mysql

I have 3 function in my java project as follows. This structure is provided in an interface named **PropertyInterface**

> > // to add the properties to Database
> >      public void addProperty (String name, String value);
> >
> > // to get the properties from DB
> >      public String getProperty (String propertyName);
> >
> > // to set the properties to DB
> >      public void setProperty (String name, String value);

A connection with the database is already established. How will I implement these functions in the **DatabaseProperty** class??

Comment: what have you [tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Actually I want to execute  the following statement in addProperty() method

"INSERT INTO APP_CONFIG VALUES("LOGMODE","0")"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you Google for ["java mysql tutorial"](http://www.google.nl/search?q=java+mysql+tutorial). Your first hit is Lars Vogels [tutorial on MySQL, Java en JDBC](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html), which will surely help you out.